# How can I determine if the back key has been pressed in a AccessibilityService, onKeyDown doesn't respond?

Tags: android, onbackpressed, accessibilityservice

I'd like to be able to know in a AccessibilityService when the user presses any system key, specifically the back key.  I've overwritten the onKeyEvent method, but it doesn't respond at all, yet I get all the events from onAccessibilityEvent.

```
@Override
public boolean onKeyEvent(KeyEvent event) {
    Log.e(TAG, "------------------- onKeyEvent ----------------------------");
    return super.onKeyEvent(event);
}
```

Following are my configuration files, I'm monitoring the AccessibilityService package (a subproject) and the actual application package.

**Manifest.xml** for the subproject containing the AccessibilityService.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

...

```
<service android:name="com.foo.MyAccessibilityService"
    android:permission="android.permission.BIND_ACCESSIBILITY_SERVICE">
  <intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.accessibilityservice.AccessibilityService" />
  </intent-filter>
  <meta-data android:name="android.accessibilityservice"
      android:resource="@xml/accessibilityservice" />
</service>
```

**accessibilityservice.xml** file is as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<accessibility-service
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:accessibilityEventTypes="typeAllMask"
android:accessibilityFeedbackType="feedbackGeneric"
android:accessibilityFlags="flagIncludeNotImportantViews"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:description="@string/emachine_accessibility_service_description"
android:settingsActivity="com.foo.services.MyAccessibilityService"
tools:ignore="UnusedAttribute"
android:canRetrieveWindowContent="true"
android:canRequestFilterKeyEvents="true"
android:canRequestTouchExplorationMode="true"/>
```

And Yes the *com.foo.services.MyAccessibilityService* is 'On' under the system Accessibility Settings.

Added

```
    android:canRequestFilterKeyEvents="true"
android:canRequestTouchExplorationMode="true"
```

to accessibility.xml in above, and the equivalent in the *onServiceConnected* was added programmatically.

```
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN_MR2) {
        info.flags |= AccessibilityServiceInfo.FLAG_REPORT_VIEW_IDS;
        info.flags |= AccessibilityServiceInfo.CAPABILITY_CAN_REQUEST_FILTER_KEY_EVENTS;
        info.flags |= AccessibilityServiceInfo.CAPABILITY_CAN_RETRIEVE_WINDOW_CONTENT;
    }
```

with no positive outcome

Answer (score 1):

I suspect that you are trying to intercept these events from a soft keyboard that is not sending them.  Key Events are only reliably sent from hardware keyboards.  In fact, manually sending the events from a software input method service is discouraged, and in prior versions of the OS lead to potentially malicious effects.  From the Android KeyEvent documentation:

> As soft input methods can use multiple and inventive ways of inputting text, there is no guarantee that any key press on a soft keyboard will generate a key event: this is left to the IME's discretion, and in fact sending such events is discouraged. You should never rely on receiving KeyEvents for any key on a soft input method. In particular, the default software keyboard will never send any key event to any application targetting Jelly Bean or later, and will only send events for some presses of the delete and return keys to applications targetting Ice Cream Sandwich or earlier. Be aware that other software input methods may never send key events regardless of the version. Consider using editor actions like IME_ACTION_DONE if you need specific interaction with the software keyboard, as it gives more visibility to the user as to how your application will react to key presses.

A cheap bluetooth keyboard is your best bet.  Or emulators with the proper configuration.

EDIT:

Alternatively you may have an error in your configuration file.  In your accessibilityservice.xml, replace this line:

```
android:accessibilityFlags="flagIncludeNotImportantViews"
```

With this:

```
android:accessibilityFlags="flagIncludeNotImportantViews|flagRequestFilterKeyEvents"
```

You can also acheive the same in your accessibility service code.

```
protected void onServiceConnected() {
    super.onServiceConnected();

    AccessibilityServiceInfo tempInfo = getServiceInfo();
    tempInfo.flags |= AccessibilityServiceInfo.FLAG_INCLUDE_NOT_IMPORTANT_VIEWS;
    tempInfo.flags |= AccessibilityServiceInfo.FLAG_REQUEST_FILTER_KEY_EVENTS;
    setServiceInfo(tempInfo);

}
```

Comment: Not at all, a system back key, not even considering anything from the soft keyboard. In a AccessibilitySERVICE I'd like to know when the system back key is pressed, i.e. going back to the previous activity. I am not talking about a back space from a ime type method.

Comment: I only wish to monitor it, not to consume it either.

Comment: The same logic applies.  The system is not required to send a key event on back arrow presses.  You're relying on implementation specifics that are not requirements.  To listen for this, a special event would have to be added for accessibility services, which is not there.  Long story short, you cannot do so reliably.

Comment: Tks. I guess I'll look into interogating the changes in the backstack to see if I can do it that way for activity changes.

Comment: What's the goal?  I've been working with the accessibility APIs for years.  I might be able to come up with a reasonable alternative...

Comment: I just want to know when the user has hit the back key and gone from Activity B to Activity A via a normal backstack.  Put another way, if the AccessessibiltyService was a Activity, I'd like to know that onBackPressed()  has been entered. I don't wish to alter the onBackPressed() execution, just know that it has occurred.

Comment: Well, knowing that the back key has been pressed, and knowing that you've gone from Activity A to Activity B are different.  The first is a much  more strict requirement.  Which one of these is it?

Comment: Preference would be onBackPressed() equivalent in a AccessibilityService

Comment: You cannot do this reliably with the current APIs.

Comment: Hey, check out the edits.  I just caught this when answering another very similar question.  I had thought on first glance, that your configuration was correct, but it is not.  You missed something.  This works for me on Droid turbo, but my comments about instability of this approach as it pertains to different hardware setups still applies, so no guarantees!